# Finding the minimum of a

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

> For constant number "a" consider the function $f(x)= ax + \cos 2x + \sin x + \cos x$ on $\mathbb R$ such that $f(u)<f(v)$ for $u< v$. If the range of a, for any real numbers $u, v$ is $[\dfrac{m}{n}, \infty)$. Find the minimum value of $(m+n)$

Attempt:

The problem is just an overly complicated way of saying "find the range for which f(x) is strictly increasing".

So, using $f'(x)>0$
I get:

$a> 2\sin 2x + \sin x - \cos x$

So basically we need to find the maximum of RHS for the range of a.

$g(x)= 2 \sin 2x + \sin x - \cos x $

For extremum, $g'(x)=0 $

$4 \cos 2x  + \cos x+ \sin x= 0$

$\implies 16\cos^2 2x = 1+ \sin 2x$

$\implies 16\sin^2 2x + \sin 2x -15 =0$

$\implies \sin 2x = -1$ or $\sin 2x = \dfrac {15}{16}$

Then it seriously gets very complicated because we would have to extract $\sin x$ and $\cos x$ from $\sin 2x = \dfrac{15}{16}$. I tried but couldn't get it easily.  After this we would have to plug in the values to g(x)
 to see which one of them gives maximum.  (Just a side note: g is periodic with period $2\pi$)

Is it possible to do this problem using my method? If not, what are the other clever ways to solve it?

Comment: You've done very well so far, but I think you've lost track of what you are trying to accomplish.  You want to find the maximum value of $g(x)$.  Can you find that if you know the associated value of $\sin 2x?$

Comment: Notice that there is no minimum value for $m + n$ unless we require $m, n$ to be positive integers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to maximize $$a=g(x)= 2\sin 2x + \sin x - \cos x=2\sin 2x + \sqrt{1-\sin 2x}$$  (I'm taking the plus sign on the square root because we only care about the maximum.)  You've found the possible values of $\sin 2x$ that maximize $a,$ so it should be plain sailing from here.

Comment: Thanks.I was struggling because I just din't convert sin x- cos x to $\sqrt {1-\sin 2x}$ :( .